# jquery tree traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a task where I need to traverse a tree (checking/un-checking individual items). I've written the code and it works correctly but slow at times. Please help me improve it.

Here is how it is suppose to work:

1. Un-checking the parent unchecks
   all children of that parent
2. Un-checking the (one or more)
   child nodes un-checks the parent
3. Checking the parent automatically
   checks all it's children
4. When all children are checked the
   parent gets checked as well
   automatically

   - this should also work with any depth tree..so if there are 3 level deep nodes unchecking the most inner child will uncheck the First parent of each node.

Few other considerations: 
Css classes:

- "checked" - black color font, when removed font is gray
- "marked" - gray background

So:

- When the parent has NO children selected, it's css class "checked" is removed (it becomes gray)
- When an item is un-checked it's css classes "checked" and "marked" are removed (black font becomes gray and without gray background)
- When ALL children are un-checked the parent's "marked" class is removed (gray background is removed).

I hope this illustration will help:
[image]

And part of HTML source code:

```
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:30px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Aparatura elektryczna, elektroenergetyka   </span></div>

<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:60px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Silniki, napędy, automatyka napęd&#243;w </span></div>
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:90px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Silniki i napędy przemysłowe </span></div>
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Prądu stałego   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Prądu przemiennego </span></div>
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>synchroniczne   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>asynchroniczne </span></div>

</li></ul></li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Silniki krokowe   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Siłowniki elektryczne   </span></div>
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Liniowe </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Obrotowe </span></div>
</li></ul></li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Serwosilniki, serwonapędy </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Inne </span></div>

</li></ul></li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:90px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Układy zabezpieczeń silnik&#243;w   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:90px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Elektroniczne układy sterowania napęd&#243;w   </span></div>
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Przemienniki prądu stałego   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Przemienniki częstotliwości (falowniki)   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Układy łagodnego rozruchu (softstarty)   </span></div>

</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Sterowniki silnik&#243;w DC </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:120px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Sterowniki silnik&#243;w krokowych </span></div>
<ul class='treeList2b'><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Jednoosiowe   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Wieloosiowe   </span></div>
</li><li class='open'>                        <div class="tlWrap clearfix marked checked" style="padding-left:150px;"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" name="SelectedBranch" id="SelectedBranch"><span>Wieloosiowe z interpolacją   </span></div>

</li></ul></li>
```

...

And my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function(){           
        $('ul.treeList2b .checkbox').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var obj = $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox'); 
            obj.attr('checked', this.checked);
            var childCnt=obj.size();  // get childrent count - when parent was clicked
            var checkedCnt=obj.filter(':checked').length; // out of those get those that are checked
            if (childCnt==checkedCnt){
                obj.parents('li').each(function (index, element) {
                    var objSub = $(element).find('li');
                    childCnt = objSub.size();
                    checkedCnt = objSub.find(':checkbox:checked').length;
                    if (childCnt==checkedCnt) { 
                        $(element).find(':checkbox:first').attr("checked", true);
                        $(element).children('div.tlWrap').addClass('checked');
                    }
                    $(element).children('div.tlWrap').addClass('marked');
                });
            }else{ 
                var objParent = obj.parents('li').find(':checkbox:first');
                objParent.attr("checked", false);
                objParent.parent('div.tlWrap').removeClass('checked');
            }
            refleshCheckbox(this);
        });
    });
    function refleshCheckbox(obj){
        if(!$(obj).attr('checked')){
            $(obj).closest('li').find('div.tlWrap').removeClass('marked');
        } 
        if ($(obj).closest('ul').find(':checkbox:checked').length==0){
            $(obj).closest('ul').parent().find('div.tlWrap').removeClass('marked');
        }
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't be adding all the functionality to this answer since you'll learn more by implementing them yourself. But I made a [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/Xxnba/) that works as illustrated:

```
$(".option-tree > li > label > input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        options = $this.closest("li").find("> ul > li > label > input:checkbox");

    $this.change(function(){
        options.prop("checked", $this[0].checked);
    });

    options.change(function(){
        var  all = options.length,
           checked = options.filter(":checked").length;
        $this[0].checked = all === checked;
    });

});
```

Note that the above example is using [jQuery 1.6](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Changelog/1.6) where you have to use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`.removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

For earlier versions of jQuery (pre 1.6) it would look like this:

```
$(".option-tree > li > label > input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        options = $this.closest("li").find("> ul > li > label > input:checkbox");

    $this.change(function(){
        if ($this[0].checked) {
            options.attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            options.removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });

    options.change(function(){
        var  all = options.length,
           checked = options.filter(":checked").length;
        $this[0].checked = all === checked;
    });

});
```